# Is there a way to reset my Mac Ruby?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I've been doing a lot to try and resolve some Rubygems SSL issues I've had on my Mac, but every time I fix an error a new one pops up. At this point I'm worried I might have messed something up somewhere along the line. Is there a way I can just do a clean reinstall of Ruby like I would have on a new Mac?

Comment: Do you use a Ruby version manager like rbenv or RVM?

Comment: Does it come with OSX? I have a rbenv folder but I don't recall installing it. But yes, I assume if I have the rbenv folder I have rbenv

Comment: What does `which ruby` and `rbenv versions` return on the command line?

Comment: `Alexs-MBP:~ alextyshka$ which ruby
/Users/alextyshka/.rbenv/shims/ruby
Alexs-MBP:~ alextyshka$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.2.0 (set by /Users/alextyshka/.rbenv/version)`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting

Comment: Put the results of questions we ask into your question, not in comments. Using the question keeps the information in one place. If it's in comments we have to read them all and figure out the order. Edit your question and add the information in as if you'd put it there initially, appropriately formatting it for readability. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags as we can tell what changed and when if we need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall your current version of Ruby run the following command in your terminal:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.2.0
```

To reinstall the same version run:

```
rbenv install 2.2.0
```

Or you might want to install a newer version. Run `ruby-build --definitions` to check what other versions are available on your system.

You probably used homebrew to install rbenv. To update rbenv (to get more recent Rubies available) run:

```
brew update
brew upgrade ruby-build
brew upgrade rbenv
```

Comment: Ok, this is pretty foolproof, right? I shouldn't get errors that leave me with no ruby at all after uninstalling?

Comment: No worries, there is still that version of Ruby that came with Mac OSX on your machine.

Comment: I ran `rbenv uninstall 2.2.0` and I got hundreds of lines of "permission denied"

Comment: Yes, rbenv's Ruby versions are completely separated from that Ruby version that comes with Mac OS. But system Ruby is usually a pretty old version. Mac OS Sierra for example comes with Ruby 2.0. Therefore it makes sense to install a newer version with with rbenv or RVM

Comment: It's possible you installed `rbenv` as `sudo` or `root` which can mess things up. You might need to `chown` all those files back to yourself to recover.

Comment: Update: Tried it again using `sudo rbenv uninstall 2.2.0` and it asked for password and whether I wanted to remove. I typed "yes" and nothing happened

Comment: Nothing happens means it was uninstalled, there is no extra message that it was successful.

Comment: When reinstalling should I use `sudo`?

Comment: Whenever possible avoid `sudo`. It might depend on your setup and how you installed homebrew and rbenv, but in my machine there is no need for `sudo` to install an new Ruby version with rbenv.

Comment: Ran into some problems running `brew update`  `Alexs-MBP:~ alextyshka$ sudo brew update
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in "require": cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)`

Comment: Seems like you system Ruby is missing a gem that is required by homebrew. Just run `gem install mach` and retry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143631/discussion-between-a-tyshka-and-spickermann).

Comment: @Ade Do you have brew and rbenv installed?

Comment: @spickermann No, the system has ruby preinstalled. I've not used rbenv.